# Create a treeview / dynamic table and filtering blanks in excel

Tags: excel

With this table:

```
A------B------C------D-------
Green--Bird------------------
Blue---Bird---Circle---------
Green--Cat-------------------
Red----Bird---Square-S-------
Red----Cat-------------------
```

I need this output in a treeview:

```
Green
--Bird
--Cat
Blue
--Bird
----Circle
Red
--Bird
----Square
------S
--Cat
```

If I allow the blanks, a pivot table does the trick but looks awful.

If I deselect the blanks, let's say for the C column, the entire C level gets hidden if a blank is present, which it is.

Is there a way to create a treeview in a sharable document I can send to someone without additional libraries?

Comment: Pivot table will give you exact output.

Comment: In pivot table there will be button to expand or collapse row label (+/- buttons) which will work like tree view.

Comment: @Harun24HR Sorry. I thought you meant the pivot function on power query. The Pivot function removes the first columns if you filter the blanks as I described in the topic.

Comment: You can do this in VBA very easily using dictionaries.

Comment: Cannyou give me an example?